# How to convert mmmm-YYYY pattern String to Date in MS Access?

Tags: sql, database, datetime, ms-access

Column **Period** datatype is String/Text

Example is: 'January-2020'

Is it possible to convert it to Date?Ex. 1-January-2020

Database is MS Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the string into a date format, that your Access version understands.

This will depend on the language of Office, and perhaps the regional settings for date.

Try "January 1 2020", i.e.

```
CDate(Replace([Period], "-", " 1 "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. `"1-" & [Period]`

Answer (score 1):

All you need is *CDate*:

```
TrueDate: CDate([Period])
```